# How to tell a StreamBuilder that I'm retrying to load data after an error

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, stream-builder

I have a stream builder for loading a list of video posts. Whenever an error occurs, I add an error to the sink and the **StreamBuilder** displays an error message with a "Try Again" button. My issue is that when I press the button, Nothing (visually) happens but I want to replace the error message with a **spinningLoader** while it's retrying.

How would I achieve this?

I was thinking of adding a boolean to the sink and check if snapshot.data is bool and return the spinningLoader if it is, but this seems counter-intuitive.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        color: backgroundColor,
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _streamController.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return buildRelatedList(snapshot.data);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return retryButton();
            } else {
              return _spinningLoader;
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _fetchVideos() async {
    List videos = await RelatedVideos.fetchVideos(
        id: widget.id);
    if (videos.isEmpty) {
      _streamController.sink.addError('error loading');
    } else {
      _streamController.sink.add(videos);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The [AsyncSnapshot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) has a `connectionState` property that will tell you if it's [waiting or done](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html). This should help you deal with showing a loading screen.

Comment: I've done some tests and the waiting state seems to end when an error is added to the sink. So when I press the retry button, it's fetching posts in the background but the button still displays. How would I tell it to enter the waiting state again?

Comment: One way I've got around that previously is to create an abstract `State` class and add that to the stream. So instead of the stream returning a `List<String>` It returns an instance of `SuccessState` which has a `results` property of type `List<String>` then on retry you can add an instance of `LoadingState` to your stream and show the loading spinner.

Comment: @JordanDavies I like how this sounds, I'm going to implement this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConnectionState`:

```
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError)
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none: return Text('Select lot');
      case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Awaiting bids...');
      case ConnectionState.active: return Text('\$${snapshot.data}');
      case ConnectionState.done: return Text('\$${snapshot.data} (closed)');
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
)
```

That will return the state of connection to an asynchronous computation. Also you can change the `Text` widget to another widget, for example you can use  `CircularProgressIndicator();`

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: I've played with connectionstate and I could not get the behavior I wanted, I returned the spinning loader when it's waiting (which works fine), but when it gets an error, I believe the state changes to active. But what I want was to change the state back to waiting when I press the retry button so I can show the spinning loader.

Comment: When you get an error is it not entering if(snapshot.hasError)?

Comment: Yes, but there is no way to show the loader after an error (using the connectionState).

Comment: Why don't u use `CircularProgressIndicator()`? That will show a loader..

Comment: did you try using `CircularProgressIndicator()`

Comment: The issue kemist is trying to raise is that after an error the connection state never goes back to 'waiting'. It'll always stay as 'active'. So if you'r eshowing an indicator when the state is 'waiting', you're out of luck.